# Splitting an item in a list based on words' order

Tags: python, split

so i have list, this is one of the item:
'Sent: Saturday, January 13, 2022 8:55 AM'
i only need the part "January 13, 2022 8:55" but split into two items "January 13, 2022" and "8:55". i know i can use split, but the problem is this item is subject to change, so i need a code that can work regardless of the change in the item (example of change: 'Sent: Tuesday, May 17, 2021 9:55 AM'). most of the answers i found split the data based on the number of characters or based on specific words, which won't work on my case because the data is subject to change. i'm looking for answers that split the item based on the number of words but got no clue.
any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you have tried and where an error occurs to allow us to help better.

Comment: Would splitting by whitespace or " " achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'Sent: Saturday, January 13, 2022 8:55 AM' 

textAsList = text.split()

newText = textAsList[2]+ ' ' + textAsList[3] + ' ' + textAsList[4] + ' ' + textAsList[5] + ' ' + textAsList[6]

print(newText)
```

Comment: If the desired info is always at the 2nd index and onwards, `newText` can be 
`" ".join(textAsList[2:])`